# Scope and Lifetime of Inline Variables Declared in Nested Blocks, Do the scope apply for Objects as well?

Tags: delphi

Do i have to run FreeAndNil on the object later on to free the memory allocated for the object or it will be handled by the new scope functionality by delphi?

```
    begin
      var foo := TObject.Create();
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to free the object manually, just as before.

The lifetime of the *object* has nothing to do with the scope of the *variable*. This has always been the case, and still applies. (Indeed, it is very much possible to create an object without assigning it to a variable at all.)

Even in this old-school example, the object would be leaked without the `Free`, even though the `Bitmap` variable goes out of scope at the procedure's `end;`.

```
procedure Test;
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    // use the bitmap
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Without `Bitmap.Free`, the object would still exist on the heap (and it might continue to use any non-memory resources it has access to), even though you have misplaced your last pointer to it!

Comment: i forgot to say i am using delphi 10.4, the website said that managed records and interface references are handled with no manual cleaning required.
https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-inline-variables-delphi.html

Comment: Records and classes are two very different things (and they have always been). `TObject` is a class, not a record.

Comment: Yeah i know but the object has an interface with the function free, so is it called in the end of the scope, i find really strange that i can use inline var to create an object inside the try block and then i cant reach it in the finally scope obviously but its not freed automatically, i mean this sound like a bug for me...

Comment: What do you mean by "the object has an interface with the function free"? `TObject.Free` is a method of `TObject` and so all Delphi objects have this method. And it is not called automatically for non-interfaced objects.

Comment: Easy on me i came from another language background (Java, C#, ... C family) and i am trying to understand. So i was confused by a std class having a function without implementing an interface. we learn the hard way right?!, thanks allot :)
i was hoping that some magic will handle the memory like in rust programming language scopes ...

Comment: No problem. Well, if you want the lifetimes to be handled automatically, you need to abandon usual non-interfaced objects and instead use records or interfaces. The new [custom managed records](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2020-may-custom-managed-records.html) in Delphi 10.4 are pretty awesome, and you might find that they offer a lot of the functionality you expect from other languages.

Comment: @HAK In Delphi `.Free` is implemented as a virtual method in the base `TObject` which all other classes inherit from.  This is different from C#, for example, where IDisposable is implemented as an interface.  Interface semantics are different in other ways also - in Delphi you can refer to the same object using class references or interface references.  Magic is not applied unless you use interface references, so mixing class and interface references comes with its own list of caveats (if, eg, your last interface reference goes out of scope for an object you still have a class reference for!)

Comment: @J...: Nitpicking: `TObject.Free` isn't virtual, but it calls (assuming `Self` isn't `nil`) `TObject.Destroy` which is.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I meant `Destroy`.  Derp.